# rails 3.2 broke images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was precompiling assets in production environment (apache + passenger) when accidentalment interrupt the process. (many shells open, closing the wrong one)

I run rake again, and the command run until finish. No errors.

The problem is that from these momment the app is not showing more the images and appear broken (image not found).

If i run the app in development environment (rails server) all is ok.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'devise'

gem 'ttfunk'
gem 'prawn', :git => "https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn.git", :ref => '8028ca0cd2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'debugger'
end
```

Comment: Which user did you run the precompile as? and is the site owned by this user?

Comment: Yes, the user is the owner. Is the same user (ordinary user, not superuser) that run the rake and te rails server in development.
Ruby and Rails are owned by the user too (installed via RVM).
Apache and Passenger owned by root. But the trigger, I think was the interrupted rake command. Until that, all works ok.

Comment: I don't suppose you tried to turn it off and turn it on again ... Trash the assets directory in /public **rm -rf /public/assets** and run the rake command again?